# tikzpicture misalignment

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a very annoying problemn regarding the `tikzpicture` environment. when I place a picture and a rectangle, which should sit in the corner of the picuter, it doesnt do so. I've provided an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] at (0,0){\includegraphics[width=5cm]{test.jpg}};
        \fill [black] (3,0) rectangle (5,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end {document}
```

It gives me the following output (zoomed in):

[image: Minimal working example]

As you can see, the rectangle (black) and the image (red) don't align, even though they should. It's only like 0.1mm, but still it is annoying me. Do you know any solution?

Thanks,
Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems :

- you should also add `outer sep=0`;
- the width of the image is not exactly `5cm` but I don't know how to correct this precision problem.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0,outer sep=0] at (0,0){\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}};
      \fill [red] (3,0) rectangle (5,2) (0,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Adding `outer sep=0` did it for me, no more misalignment, thanks